# Java Prepared statement not entering data and hits the catch

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, prepared-statement

I am currently writing some SQL for a larger program. Originally I was using SQL raw queries (which worked) and then I switched to Prepared statements for security and tidiness.

Unfortunately the statements are not executing my inserts or any other SQL function and I keep hitting the catch in my try catch block. The message it gives is **Query does not return results** However I understand that this message on its own doesn't necessarily indicate an error.

Here is my code, any help is much appreciated

```
 public User createNewUser(String email, String publicKey, int balance, String privateKey, int units, String type)
 {

    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);)
    {
        //create new user in the db
        String query = "INSERT INTO " + USER_TABLE_NAME + " (email, publicKey, privateKey, balance) " +
                "Values(?, ?, ?, ?)";

        PreparedStatement makeNewUser = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        makeNewUser.setString(1, email);
        makeNewUser.setString(2, publicKey);
        makeNewUser.setString(3, privateKey);
        makeNewUser.setInt(4, balance)

        ResultSet newUser = makeNewUser.executeQuery();
        newUser.next();
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println("EPIC FAIL " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
```

and here is the table schema for users:

```
    static String createUserTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + USER_TABLE_NAME + "(\n"
        + " id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,\n"
        + " email text UNIQUE NOT NULL,\n"
        + " publicKey Text UNIQUE NOT NULL, \n"
        + " privateKey Text UNIQUE NOT NULL, \n"
        + " balance INTEGER NOT NULL \n"
        + ");";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
ResultSet newUser = makeNewUser.executeQuery();
```

to use [`PreparedStatement.executeUpdate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate--)

```
makeNewUser.executeUpdate();
```

Your insert doesn't return a `ResultSet`.